# How to connect jquery tooltip with asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I tried to connect some jquery plugin tooltip with asp.net Textbox, but with failure result.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../chosen/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../chosen/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () { //shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){...});
        $('textbox').qtip({
            content: 'Short hand notation'
        })
    });
</script>

 <asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox" ID="textbox" name="textbox"
 runat="server"/>
```

Error:

> qtip is not a function

Is there anybody who can show me how to connect some elegant jquery tooltip plugin with standard textbox from asp.net?

Regards

Comment: Where is the code?  If you give us something to work with that would help.  The general method is to reference only part of the id with jquery.  Then jquery will find the mangled id for your textbox.

Comment: oh, sorry - I don't know why my code disappeared in topic.

Comment: You have already ask that. What is the difference here ?

Comment: diffrence: in this topic I ask for another solution than qtip. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545544/qtip2-jquery-with-asp-net-textbox topic I asked for solution only for qtip.

Comment: Please add the page from where you have get the qTip, where is the source code and the home of qTip ?

Comment: Your selector is wrong, it would either need to be `$("#textbox").qtip()` or `$(".textbox").qtip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out: *For safer side don't use the same ID & CSS class name for Textbox.*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../chosen/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../chosen/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('myTextbox').qtip({
        content: 'Short hand notation',
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout'
    })
});
</script>

<asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox" ID="myTextbox" name="myTextbox" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: this works, but only if `CssClass="myTextbox"`, not CssClass="textbox".

Comment: @whoah: Then better change your CSS class name.

Comment: Surely, it would need to be a `<myTextbox>` element.